# Changing syntax with regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I am having some trouble with ruby syntax in chef (the configuration management tool).

The difference I am dealing with is assigning attributes such as below:

```
runner = ChefSpec::Runner.new(platform: "ubuntu", version: version)
runner = ChefSpec::Runner.new(:platform => "ubuntu", :version => version)
```

I need to be able to switch between these two syntax's as they seem to work in different versions of chef/ruby - we will be upgrading but for now need a fix.

I'm novice with regexp, but have been trying like this in python:

```
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
  line = re.sub('(\w\w...): ',':"\1" =>', line.rstrip())
  print(line)
```

I don't know what the attribute name will be, or what precedes it, only that a single `:` follows a word (of 2 or more characterss).  I'm happy assuming that there will always be a space after the `:` but I seem to be having trouble "picking up" the attribute name to replace and re-use later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following should work:

```
for line in fileinput.input(inplace=1, backup='.bak'):
  line = re.sub('(\w+): ', ':\g<1> => ', line.rstrip())
  print(line)
```

see [regex demo](http://regex101.com/#python), or [repl demo](http://repl.it/Whl)

Comment: Seems to be spot on! Thanks for the quick reply. I still need to work out exactly why it's that syntax, but all part of learning. Cheers